# mysql: [ERROR] unknown option '--CREATE TABLE users (id INT, name CHAR);'

Tags: mysql

I tried to create a table named *users* by `CREATE TABLE users (id INT, name CHAR);`. Now, I can't start mysql from console, the error is as follows:

> mysql: [ERROR] unknown option '--CREATE TABLE users (id INT, name CHAR);'.

Comment: It looks like you are single quoting users - this is not valid in mysql - you should use backticks or nothing at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: i didl't use quotes.

Comment: What command are you using to start the mysql command line client?

Answer (score -1):

**The CREATE TABLE statement is used to create a table in MySQL.**

NOT NULL - Each row must contain a value for that column, null values are not allowed

DEFAULT value - Set a default value that is added when no other value is passed

UNSIGNED - Used for number types, limits the stored data to positive numbers and zero

AUTO INCREMENT - MySQL automatically increases the value of the field by 1 each time a new record is added

PRIMARY KEY - Used to uniquely identify the rows in a table. The column with PRIMARY KEY setting is often an ID number, and is often used with AUTO_INCREMENT

Each table should have a primary key column (in this case: the "id" column). Its value must be unique for each record in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: The primary key for a table is not necessary and is optional.

Comment: the problem is that i can't start mysql to fix the table.